# Bootstrap Carousel is not showing up on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add bootstrap carousel, when I do inspect element, the dom is available but it is not showing up.

I am using the customized Bootstrap library which I downloaded form this link:

[BootStrap Custom Link](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/?id=016dc03f7bed5187e26d2b8ec7e1827d)

What i am missing in my template.

this is what I tried:

html:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
          <img class="first-slide" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="First slide">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>Example headline.</h1>
              <p>Note: If you're viewing this page via a <code>file://</code> URL, the "next" and "previous" Glyphicon buttons on the left and right might not load/display properly due to web browser security rules.</p>
              <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Sign up today</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img class="second-slide" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Second slide">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>Another example headline.</h1>
              <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
              <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img class="third-slide" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Third slide">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>
              <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
              <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Browse gallery</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
$('#myCarousel').carousel();
```

[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/68hf5y33/2/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every thing is fine in your code just you need to have image height and width use below css it will solve your issue.

```
.carousel-inner > .item >img{
  min-height : 300px;
  max-height : 300px;
  width : 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just need to give height to `.container` class as below:

```
.container{
  height:300px;
}
```

But, I would prefer to change `container` class name to `custom-container`. Because bootstrap already uses `container` as class name. So it would be better to be away from expected conflicts.

Here is working jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/68hf5y33/3/

Comment: you can't fix container height as it will effect where ever you use the same class

Answer (score -1):

As you're using Bootstrap, you need the class `.active` in one of the sliding `<div>` elements for it to be able to show.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).